# How to convert Label to a DateTime format asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, gridview, label

hi does anybody know how can i convert the label value from `lbl_reviewDate` to a `DateTime` format so that i can compare it with `DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6)` the code below is the logic i want to implement.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    Button reviewDate = e.Row.FindControl("ButtonReview") as Button;
    Label lastReview = e.Row.FindControl("lbl_reviewDate") as Label;

    if (lastReview == null || **(lbl_reviewDate as a DateTime format)** == DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6))
    {
      reviewDate.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
      reviewDate.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime(lastReview.Text)` will convert you to date. Better make sure you receive a date from that label else will result in exception

Comment: What is the format of the date in lbl_reviewDate? Can it be any format?

Comment: @codersl the format is `DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("d");`

Comment: @Suprabhat i tried this method but it doesnt seem to work. i want to compare the value of the label which is a date to be compared to the date 6 months later so the button will be visible.

Comment: Equality condition might be failing due to the differences in time components of a Datetime. Use DateTime.Date property for comparison. This will return you the same dates but with Time component set to 12:00 midnight.

Comment: @alicewannabe: Just made a sample for Date comparison have a look at it, this can solve your problem [Date Comparison](https://ideone.com/JVo7bu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a date string based on the short date format ("d") and current culture:

```
string datePattern = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
DateTime reviewDate = DateTime.ParseExact(lbl_reviewDate.Text, datePattern, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

or if you already know the date format then you can just specify it:

```
DateTime reviewDate = DateTime.ParseExact(lbl_reviewDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: hi thanks but i have more questions, is it correct that i compare this converted DateTime to `DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6)` cos i want to compare the date from the label to the date 6 months later. can u pls advise me.

Comment: If lbl_reviewDate is Jan 1st, 2015 then reviewDate.AddMonths(6) is July 1st, 2015. I think you want to check DateTime.Now.Date >= reviewDate.AddMonths(6)? (ie. more than 6 months has elapsed since last review)